# Piping file contents to conky?

Tags: linux, conky

I have been writing a script to check the weather.  The script is fine and is working great as a cronjob but, I am now trying to have the results from the script(todays weather forecast) displayed in conky.

I have a file 'weather-outside' that the python-weather script writes to then I add this to the conkyrc file:

```
${color grey}Weather:${scroll 16 $execi 3600 cat $/home/User/Desktop/misc./weather-outside | fold}
```

The **execi** command is suppose to run at interval set to 3600secs but, this is the error message when running conky after:

```
Conky: execi needs arguments
Conky: Error destroying thread
***** Imlib2 Developer Warning ***** :
    This program is calling the Imlib call:

    imlib_context_free();

    With the parameter:

    context

    being NULL. Please fix your program.
```

I have changed **execi** to **exec** but, then the actually line 'cat $home/User/Desktop/misc./weather-outside | fold' scrolls across conky not the text from that file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use file to get the information to display in conky. I don't know how you do it in Python but when I wrote Java application to get twitter feed to be displayed in conky I directly printed it to the console and used execi. This is how I used it

```
${execi 600 java -cp /home/aman/java/classes MyApp}
```

Also your file path seems odd to me.

This way you can keep weather info updated without having to update the text file too.

Comment: Thanks Aman for the advice!  Not updating a separate file and printing the information into the console is what I wanted to do initially but, didn't know how. :D The final line `${color grey}Weather:${scroll 16 ${execi 600 /home/User/Desktop/misc././weather.py | fold}}`.  I don't know if your `cp` was the `copy` command or what but, I didn't need to put it in.

Comment: @tijko cp here stands for classpath and is java specific. so no worry for you!

Comment: hey :) thanks for getting back to me.  I would have just kept thinking it probably meant `cp` as in the terminal command in linux.

Comment: have you checked http://www.crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/59/my-conky-config/page/65/ they have many rc files there.

Comment: I haven't checked too much into crunchbanglinux but, it seems like its pretty hot right now.  `${color grey}Weather:${scroll 20 20 %{execi 400 /home/User/Desktop/misc././weather.py | fold}}` is what I have right now its working pretty good.  I will definitely check out crunchbanglinux too.  Thanks again!